# Get .jar file from local maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle

I am publishing my .jar files to the local .m2 repository. I just need to copy that jar afterwards into a custom folder.

I don't need need to add any dependency, just get a file. What is the simplest way to make a copy task of a specific .jar from local repository without hardcoding its path?

Comment: Is that jar created with the script owned by you? If so you can publish this jar and then copy it directly from the project - without using local repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
configurations { copyDeployable }

dependencies {
    copyDeployable "<group>:<artifact>:<version>@jar"
}

task copyJar(type: Copy) {

    from project.configurations.copyDeployable.singleFile
    into "/whatever/file/path/"
}
```